# ICredentialRepository service must be configured in order to use this feature

Tags: java, one-time-password

from https://github.com/wstrange/GoogleAuth

when setting credentials for a user:

`GoogleAuthenticator gAuth = new GoogleAuthenticator();
final GoogleAuthenticatorKey key = gAuth.createCredentials("daryll123");`

exception occured:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: An instance of the com.warrenstrange.googleauth.ICredentialRepository service must be configured in order to use this feature.`

How do I have to configure using `ICredentialRepository` in order to work?
There it states Java ServiceLoader API. No idea what is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement the ICredentialRepository interface methods somewhere, and set that class as the credential repository on your gAuth variable using

```
setCredentialRepository()
```

If you implement the methods on the current class, you can use

```
gAuth.setCredentialRepository(this)
```

The interface methods are

```
String getSecretKey(String userName);
```

and

```
void saveUserCredentials(String userName,
                         String secretKey,
                         int validationCode,
                         List<Integer> scratchCodes);
```

The error is confusing, because it doesn't give the context that your credential repository is not set up properly. Hope this helps!